# Filtering data in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
S1State S1Value S2State S2Value
NSW     20      VIC     30
WA      30      NSW     20
```

I would like to filter and select the state(from S1State and S2State) that has the maximum value(from S1Value and S2Value). The result should look like this:

```
SState  SValue
VIC     30
WA      30
```

I am new to R and have been experimenting with dplyr.

Comment: Start with `mutate(df, SState = ifelse( ... ))`, where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: I think you'd be better off re-formatting your data. Not sure of the dplyr equivalent but `reshape(dt, direction="long", varying=list(c(1,3),c(2,4)), v.names=c("State","Value"))` is what you want. Working with long data will be a lot easier no matter what packages you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the OP may have more states in the data frame, such as `S3State`, `S4State`, ...

The following solutions are based on this assumption, trying to be able to process more than one states. If there are only two states, the approach proposed by @lebelinoz is simple and straightforward.

#### Solution 1

A solution using functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Num, Value, contains("Value")) %>%
  gather(State, Name, contains("State")) %>%
  # Only keep records with the same state number
  filter(substring(Num, 1, 2) == substring(State, 1, 2)) %>%
  mutate(Group = substring(Num, 1, 2)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(Value == max(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(SState = Name, SSValue = Value)
```

#### Solution 2

A solution using functions from `dplyr`, `purrr`, and `stringr`. I loaded the package `tidyverse` for the first two packages. Again, `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Extract the column names
Col <- colnames(dt)

# Extract state numbers
ColNum <- Col %>%
  str_extract(pattern = "[0-9]") %>%
  unique()

# Design a function to process the data
dt_process <- function(pattern, dt){
  dt2 <- dt %>%
    # Extract columns based on a pattern (numbers)
    select(dplyr::contains(pattern)) %>%
    # Rename the columns
    rename_all(~sub(pattern, "", .)) %>%
    # Filter the maximum row
    filter(SValue == max(SValue))
  return(dt2)
}

# Apply the dt_process function
dt_list <- map(.x = ColNum, .f = dt_process, dt = dt)

# Bind all data frames
dt2 <- bind_rows(dt_list) %>% arrange(SState)
```

#### Data Preparation

```
# Create example data frame
    dt <- read.table(text = "S1State S1Value S2State S2Value
                     NSW     20      VIC     30
                     WA      30      NSW     20",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer I was hinting at is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- read.table(text = "S1State S1Value S2State S2Value
                 NSW     20      VIC     30
                 WA      30      NSW     20",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
answer = dt %>% 
  mutate(SState = ifelse(S1Value > S2Value, S1State, S2State), 
         SValue = ifelse(S1Value > S2Value, S1Value, S2Value)) %>%
  select(SState, SValue)
```

Comment: It is a valid answer, but I was thinking it is possible that the OP has more than 2 States to work with, such as `S3State`, `S4State`, ...

Comment: @ycw Sure, if that's the case then yours is the better answer.

Comment: ...but the question says "I am new to R and have been experimenting with dplyr". Simplicity is probably best. Here, I use only `select`, `mutate` and the `%>%` pipe

Comment: I agree that simplicity is important. My approach is probably too convoluted. But I feel like keeping both answers here in this post could be beneficial, which demonstrates the capacity using R to process data.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me on this. @ycw is correct in assuming that I have more than 2 states to work with such as s3state, s4state and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show that this is far from impossible with standard R tools:

```
nams <- c("State","Value")
tmp  <- reshape(dt, direction="long", varying=lapply(nams, grep, x=names(dt)),
                v.names=nams, timevar=NULL)
tmp[with(tmp, Value == ave(Value, id, FUN=max)),]
#    State Value id
#2.1    WA    30  2
#1.2   VIC    30  1
```